# Spring application call last ajax call after login

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc, get

I am facing big problem from last few days.

When I search for any value in my application and if session is expired already, my application redirects to login page which is perfect.

But when I login again, application is showing last GET ajax call (for which I was searching for) and shows resultant JSON in browser. But it should show home page.

My code as follows;

```
// Document Ready() Starts

$("#grid_id").jqGrid({
                url :"search/getHouseholdHistoryList",
                async : false,
                type: 'GET',
                datatype: 'json',
                postData: {
                    searchHHID: function() { return $("#txt_SearchID").val(); },
                    filterKey:  function() { return $('#ulSearch_TypeOfID li.selected').attr('value') }
                },
                colNames:mainGridColNames,
                colModel: [
                    { name:'incidentID', index:'incidentID', width:110,sortable:true},
                    { name:'incidentCreatedDate', index:'incidentCreatedDate', width:160, sortable:false},
                    { name:'incidentSummary', index:'incidentSummary', width:482,sortable:false},
                    { name:'incidentStatus', index:'incidentStatus', width:120, sortable:false},
                    { name:'actionLink', index:'actionLink', width:100, sortable:false}
                ],
                viewrecords: true,
                //autowidth:true,
                width: '100%',
                height:'150',
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList:[10,20,30], 
                rownumbers: false,
                sortorder: "desc",
                ignoreCase: true,
                loadonce: true,
                jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
                pager: 'gridpager',
                direction:'ltr'
            }).jqGrid('navGrid','gridpager',
                      {edit:false, add:false, del:false, search:true, refresh:true});

//Document Ready() Ends
```

I am using 
-Spring mvc.
-JSP
-Jquery
-Ajax

Please let me know if anything else required.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're submitting your ajax request while you're viewing your application from an expired session.  So as soon as the secured "search/getHouseholdHistoryList" endpoint is hit, Spring Security prompts you to login to display the result.  It has no knowledge of where you left off in your application, in your previous (now expired session).  So all it knows to do is return the results of "search/getHouseholdHistoryList" to your browser.

You would need to check if your session is expired before submitting the request and have the page redirect to the login page.  I'm not familiar enough with the Spring Security JSP tags since I don't use JSP, but there must be a method to check the validity of the current session in some form and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks i will try this manual validation of session before requesting. Was hoping some inbuilt feature of Spring.